# Raspberry Pi can't install any packages with pip

Tags: python, packages, pip

So the other day, while trying to install a pip package for a project, I noticed that I was getting error messages. I tried anything that I could think of, even uninstalling python and pip, and reinstalling. Sadly, I am out of ideas and have no viable backup for my machine. Any suggestions?

The error I get for every package I try to install

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting defusedxml
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 338, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 218, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 164, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 572, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 534, in find_all_candidates
    self._package_versions(page.iter_links(), search)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 702, in _package_versions
    v = self._link_package_versions(link, search)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 777, in _link_package_versions
    support_this_python = check_requires_python(link.requires_python)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/packaging.py", line 33, in check_requires_python
    return python_version in requires_python_specifier
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/packaging-19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/packaging/specifiers.py", line 676, in __contains__
    return self.contains(item)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/packaging-19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/packaging/specifiers.py", line 681, in contains
    item = parse(item)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/packaging-19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/packaging/version.py", line 28, in parse
    return Version(version)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/packaging-19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/packaging/version.py", line 219, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Welp, for anyone having the same issue just try

`sudo pip`

Comment: If you uninstalled python and don't have a backup do a fresh install. Your system is broken.